# Macro definition for array value

Tags: c

Is there a way to define macro for value in array:

For exemple I have :

```c
#define COMSS_GETNBERNEWVALUE       uca1_NbreReceivedValue
#define COMSS_GETNBERNEWVALUE2      uca2_NbreReceivedValue
#define COMSS_GETNBERNEWVALUETEST   uca6_NbreReceivedValue
```

And I would like to store 2 similar data in a macro definition. Something like this:

```c
#define COMSS_GETNBERNEWVALUE[3]   {uca1_NbreReceivedValue,uca2_NbreReceivedValue, uca6_NbreReceivedValue}
```

Comment: Possibly answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36493446/4226702)

Comment: why not a `const array` ?

Comment: `ucaX_NbreReceivedValue` is a counter of UART received bytes, it is not constant.

Comment: @Clément please show the declaration of `uca1_NbreReceivedValue` and `uca2_NbreReceivedValue` for completeness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with `[]` but you can do this:

```
#define COMSS_GETNBERNEWVALUE(a)   uca##a##_NbreReceivedValue
```

Then `COMSS_GETNBERNEWVALUE(1)` will be substituted with `uca1_NbreReceivedValue`, `COMSS_GETNBERNEWVALUE(2)` will be substituted with `uca2_NbreReceivedValue` etc.

Bu you cannot use this method if instead of having `uca1_NbreReceivedValue`, `uca2_NbreReceivedValue` etc. you have `ucaFirst_NbreReceivedValue`, `uca1_NbreReceivedValue`.

Comment: I didn't know that but it wouldn't be good for my case since `a` is not equal and could be absolutly not related to the name of `ucX_NbreReceivedValue`

Comment: @Clément in that case I suppose you can't do it with macros